# git - zip changed files of specified commit

Tags: git, powershell, github, bitbucket

I have PS command, which zipping all changed files from last commit:

```
powershell "git archive -o "./../__updates/$(git log -1 --pretty=%B).zip" HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)"
```

Now, how can I zip another commit based on SHA, eg. `8272fa8`?

And how can I use this command automatically, eg. after every commit?

@Mark Adelsberger
I have 2 commits:
**Commit:** 8272fa8
**Strong:** b50d426a01

Where:
**8272fa8** has files:

- index.php
- assets/style.css
- images/logo.png

and **b50d426a01** has files:

- lib/Image.php

When I use:

```
git archive -o "./../__updates/$(git log -1 --pretty=%B).zip" 8272fa8 $(git diff --diff-filter=d --name-only b50d426a01^)
```

I'm getting:

```
fatal: pathspec 'storage/cache.php' did not match any files
```

From the newest commit, why?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I zip another commit based on SHA, eg. 8272fa8?

In your `archive` command, `HEAD` is one value you can give for the `<tree-ish>` -- i.e. what content to put in the archive.  The SHA ID of any `COMMIT` is also a valid `<tree-ish>`, so replace `HEAD` with your SHA ID value.

And likewise in your `diff` command `HEAD^` means "the parent commit of `HEAD`".  As long as your commit *has* a parent, you can use it's SHA in place of `HEAD` again.  So for anything but a root commit

```
powershell "git archive -o "./../__updates/$(git log -1 --pretty=%B).zip" <sha-id> $(git diff --name-only <sha-id>^)"
```

Note that if the commit for `<sha-id>` is a merge, this will diff it against its first parent (the branch *into which* other changes were merged).

If your commit *is* a root commit, then the diff doesn't make sense at all (you'd want to "diff against an empty tree", which will just return the addition of every file anyway), so you'd simply say

```
powershell "git archive -o "./../__updates/$(git log -1 --pretty=%B).zip" <sha-id>"
```

Making your script know the difference is another hoop to jump through, and in most scenarios it's not going to find the "root commit" case very often, so it might be easier to archive the root commit manually and just set up your script to assume there's a parent (and, ideally, to fail gracefully if the `diff` does error out).

> how can I use this command automatically, eg. after every commit?

I have a feeling you're dumping effort into something you'll later find was redundant, but ok.  You can run this after every commit by setting up a post-commit hook (a script in your repo's `.git/hooks` directory).  See https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Hi, thanks for great response! Hooks I'll check later, first I want to create command for archive :) When I use first option (with `diff`) I cannot create zip when some files which are created later :/ Is it possible to fix it? I know the second command but I need only changed/new files in this zip, not all ;)

Comment: I'm not following when you say *"I cannot create zip when some files which are created later"*  Can you clarify the conditions where this fails?  As I'm thinking about it, one thing that could cause a problem is file deletion; so you could try adding `--diff-filter=d` do the `diff` command.  But I'm not sure if this might sometimes cause headaches with renames/moves.

Comment: sorry for my english, I updated question for more details ;)